# How to insert array items in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

i'm making a web site with MEAN Stack

I made a schema.

below is the schema.

```
const StoreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  storename: {
    type: String
  },
  storenumber: {
    type: Number
  },
  product: [{
    pname: String,
    pcode: Number,
    price: String,
    detail: String
  }]
});
```

product is array.

when i make this schema, mongoose make it like this.

```
_id:5c3afaa96649e84364aab24b
storenumber:1
product:Array
__v:0
```

now there is a problem .

i want to insert values to pname, pcode, price, detail in product array.

but i can't push the values to the array.

below is the inserting value code.

```
module.exports.addProd = function(newProd, callback) {
 Store.updateOne({
    storenumber: number
  }, {
    $push: {
      pname: newProd.pname
    },
    $push: {
      pcode: newProd.pcode
    },
    $push: {
      price: newProd.price
    },
    $push: {
      detail: newProd.detail
    }
  }, callback);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

even i wrote product.

the values in newProd are all correct

what i want is like this

```
product[0] = {
    pname:blah, 
    pcode:1, 
    price:5, 
    detail:blah blah
}
```

how can i insert values to array in mongoose?

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to push the whole object together rather than each field like this -

```
Store.updateOne({
  storenumber: number
}, { $push: { "product": newProduct } }, callback);
```

and also rather than using callback you should use async await -

```
module.exports.addProd = async newProd => {
  let res = await Store.updateOne({
    storenumber: number
  }, { $push: { "product": newProduct } });
  return res;
}
```